# Capture text from HTML and send it to .js which includes watson API

Tags: javascript, html, watson

I am playing around with IBM watson a little bit. But since I am a rookie in HTML and JavaScript I am facing a couple of issues... 
The idea is to hand over a text to watson. Watson is responding fine. But unfortunately I have no idea how to send a text to watson from and HTML file for processing the text. I've tried already several things, but nothing worked so far. The developer tool in firefox is telling me that submitData is not defined. 
Among others I tried to capture the data with "document.getElementById("myText").value;" ... I am pretty lost right now and I can't find an answer.

I would highly appreciate any kind of help!

Cheers,
Daniel

```js
var submitData = function() {
  var ToneAnalyzerV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer/v3');
  var toneAnalyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
    username: 'XXXXXXXXX',
    password: 'XXXXXXXXX',
    version: '2016-05-19',
    url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/'
  });
  toneAnalyzer.tone({
      tone_input: 'You say hello and I say goodbye', //new
      content_type: 'text/plain'
    },
    function(err, tone) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2));
      }
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="myText">Sumbit your examplar response:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="myText"></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitData()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: You mean `tone_input: document.getElementById("myText").value,`

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note here:

It looks like you're trying to use `require` in the browser, for which you should use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) for.

You might also consider moving your `require` statement outside the scope of your function so you don't re-import the dependency every time the function runs.

You can capture your input with `document.getElementById('myText').value`

Also, it's better to put your script tag either in the `head` element or at the end of the `body` element of your document.

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="myText">Sumbit your examplar response:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="myText"></textarea>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitData()">Submit</button>

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ToneAnalyzerV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer/v3');

    var submitData = function () {

      var toneAnalyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
        username: 'XXXXXXXXX',
        password: 'XXXXXXXXX',
        version: '2016-05-19',
        url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/'
      });

      toneAnalyzer.tone({
        tone_input: document.getElementById('myText').value,  //new
        content_type: 'text/plain'
      },
        function (err, tone) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2));
          }
        }
      );
    };  
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, thank you very much for your help. I used browserify and the problem with "require" is now solved. But I still have a problem with "submitData"... It just does not work, it's still telling me that submitData is not defined. When I am do a test with a simple test.js file which contains    var submitData = function() { console.log("Test123"); }  everything works fine.... What am I doing wrong ?